# Pandas transpose raw data with inconsistent row pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following raw data export:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
     'Data': ['A15','abc','A25',50,'abc','A30',20,'def','A4','hijk','A',10,'mnop'],

    })
df
```

[image]

I am trying to transpose this raw data to a table with 3 columns: `Name, Number and Text`

I would like a row for every time `A` appears as this is the consistent pattern. After that there is always a text but only sometimes there is a number. If this number appears it is always the direct row after the `A`. My expected output is this:

[image]

Any ideas on how i can approach this? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['A15', 'abc', 'A25', 50, 'abc', 'A30', 20, 'def', 'A4', 'hijk', 'A', 10, 'mnop']})
```

convert to list:

```
flat_list = df['Data'].tolist()
```

iterate over list, if element matches `A\d+` add new sublist otherwise append to last sublist:

```
nested_list = []
while len(flat_list) > 0:
    element = flat_list.pop(0)
    if re.fullmatch("A\d*", str(element)):
        nested_list.append([element])
    else:
        nested_list[-1].append(element)
```

to list of dicts where 'Number' is np.NaN if a sublist has only two items:

```
as_records = [
    {'Name': l[0], 'Number': l[1], 'text': l[2]} if len(l) == 3 else {'Name': l[0], 'Number': np.NaN, 'text': l[1]} 
    for l in nested_list]
```

convert to DataFrame:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(as_records)
```

Which returns:

```
  Name  Number  text
0  A15     NaN   abc
1  A25    50.0   abc
2  A30    20.0   def
3   A4     NaN  hijk
4    A    10.0  mnop
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am getting the following error: `IndexError: list index out of range` which comes for the line: `nested_list[-1].append(element)`. when i debug my `element` = `A1. 01:05`

Comment: Seems like some of the elements in Name do not follow the format `"A\d*"`. You could use `if re.match("A\d*", str(element)):` so the element does not have to exactly match the 'A+optional number' pattern. However you should be aware that any text starting with an `A` will also result in a new row.

Comment: Depending on how much of a problem that is you could advance the pattern to match either just 'A', 'A+digit' or any other patterns that occur such as the one you showed: 'A+digit+dot+space+timestamp'.

Comment: Thanks! I just had to change it to `re.match` and it worked! much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can define masks and use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
m1 = df['Data'].str.startswith('A')
m2 = m1.isna() #OR: pd.to_numeric(df['Data'], errors='coerce').notna()
m1 = m1.fillna(False)

df2 = (df
 .assign(index=m1.cumsum(),
         col=np.select([m1, m2], ['Name', 'Number'], 'Text')
        )
 .pivot(index='index', columns='col', values='Data')
)
```

output:

```
col   Name Number  Text
index                  
1      A15    NaN   abc
2      A25     50   abc
3      A30     20   def
4       A4    NaN  hijk
5        A     10  mnop
```

intermediates:

```
    Data     m1  m1(v2)     m2  m1(cumsum)
0    A15   True    True  False           1
1    abc  False   False  False           1
2    A25   True    True  False           2
3     50    NaN   False   True           2
4    abc  False   False  False           2
5    A30   True    True  False           3
6     20    NaN   False   True           3
7    def  False   False  False           3
8     A4   True    True  False           4
9   hijk  False   False  False           4
10     A   True    True  False           5
11    10    NaN   False   True           5
12  mnop  False   False  False           5
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Im getting an `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` which i am guessing because i have `A` rows that have the same name?

Comment: @SOK this means you have not always the Name Number Text pattern but sometimes more than one Number/text in between Names. In this case, use `pivot_table` in place of `pivot` and chose what to use as aggregation (e.g. `aggfunc='first'` to keep only the first entry)

Comment: Thanks! Yes thats correct, sometimes its only `Name, Text` and other times it is `Name, Number, Text`. If i use `aggfunc='first'` then it just removes the `Number` column, keeping `Text` but inserting the number to the `Text` column

Comment: Weird, it shouldn't do this. Can you provide an updated example?

Comment: Im not too sure how to export the raw data but the column (as a list) looks something like this: `['A1. 01:08',
 'text 1',
 'A1. 01:12',
 '6 - Smith',
 'ABCDEFG',
 'A1. 01:13',
 '38 - Johnson',
 'HIGKLMNO']`. Im guessing because maybe the numbers are actually text in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    ss1=dd.loc[df.Data.astype(str).str.isdigit(),"Data"]
    ss2=pd.Index(dd.iloc[1:].Data).difference(ss1)
    return pd.Series(dict(Name=dd.head(1).squeeze(),Number=ss1.max(),text=ss2.max()),name=dd.name)

col1=df.Data.astype(str).str.contains("A").cumsum()
df.groupby(col1).apply(function1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

out

```
  Name  Number  text
Data                   
0     A15     NaN   abc
1     A25    50.0   abc
2     A30    20.0   def
3      A4     NaN  hijk
4       A    10.0  mnop
```